# Use Volley to get response of several ids in a list

Tags: java, android, list, android-volley

I have a list of IDs and i would like to get the data about each ID in that list. Is it possible, using volley or any other Networking library without having to call the request as the list is being looped to save execution time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO here is what i have worked on so far. To send multiple network requests of each ID, a new RequestQueue constructor (for volley) is needed.
`            RequestQueue mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);

```
        // Instantiate the cache
        Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(mContext.getCacheDir(), 1024 * 1024); // 1MB cap

        // Set up the network to use HttpURLConnection as the HTTP client.
        BasicNetwork network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());

        mRequestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network, 29);
//The Integer 29 indicate the number of requests, 
//hence, the number of concurrent threads volley will run on its Looper and 
//Handler.

        // Start the queue
        mRequestQueue.start();

       //Make request here
```

I hope it helps anyone.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can, it will only take one request IF the response contains ID then you can get the list IDs during JSON parsing.